# Creating and running a "scheduled task" once

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I have some long running (> 1 minute) tasks that use to be run fine through an xQuery in REST. However, we have now placed these servers behind an Amazon load balancer and because of the way Amazon load balancers work, no single query can have a duration exceeding 29 seconds. Amazon will just timeout the query.

NOTE: There is no control over this

So, the solution we came up with is for the xQuery to just trigger a scheduled task to run which works fine. I had thought this would work and it does with one exception --- using something like this:

```
declare function jobs:create-job ($xquery-resource as xs:string, $period as xs:integer, $job-name as xs:string, $job-parameters as element()?, $delay as xs:integer, $repeat as xs:integer) as xs:boolean {
let $jobstatus := scheduler:schedule-xquery-periodic-job($xquery-resource, $period, $job-name, $job-parameters, $delay, $repeat) 
return $jobstatus
```

And setting the $repeat to 0, it runs once but the job named "$job-title" is still in the list of scheduled jobs as "COMPLETE". Trying to run the code again will error. The error is apparently that another job with the same name cannot be created. If I change the job name it will run, so I know it is the name that is causing the error. The schedule log shows:

```
    <scheduler:job name="Create Vault">
        <scheduler:trigger name="Create Vault Trigger">
            <expression>30000</expression>
            <state>COMPLETE</state>
            <start>2019-08-22T20:07:14.775Z</start>
            <end/>
            <previous>2019-08-22T20:07:14.775Z</previous>
            <next/>
            <final/>
        </scheduler:trigger>
    </scheduler:job>
```

Now, is there a different way that we could execute an xQuery triggered only once so that we do not have this job name issue? Or a way to tell the scheduled task to self-destruct and remove itself? Otherwise we would need to write some complicated code to create another task to delete the job after it is run (or maybe the create task code should delete any $job-name jobs) or leave them behind and use some GUID on the name.

**Update I**

The cleanest way we found is this (essentially if the job exists when we go to create it, delete it and then create another one):

```
declare function jobs:create-job ($xquery-resource as xs:string, $period as xs:integer, $job-name as xs:string, $job-parameters as element()?, $delay as xs:integer, $repeat as xs:integer) as xs:boolean {
let $cleanjob:= if(count(scheduler:get-scheduled-jobs()//scheduler:job[@name=$job-name]) > 0) then scheduler:delete-scheduled-job($job-name) else true() 
let $jobstatus := if($cleanjob) then scheduler:schedule-xquery-periodic-job($xquery-resource, $period, $job-name, $job-parameters, $delay, $repeat) else false()
return $jobstatus
};
```

I would say we should also check the status and not delete if it is running ... however these tasks are built to run on-demand but the on-demand is likely once a day at most. The longest task is formatting about 3000 document to PDFSs which takes maybe 20 mins. It is not likely anyone would clash with another running task but we could add that to be sure.

Or should the answer be examining util:eval-async() but that is confusing as it does not really say that it just "shells" out the execution. If it threads it out and waits for the thread then that will not work either.

Comment: The Scheduler Module in eXist-db is a relatively thin wrapper around Quartz - http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/. I am not sure if it will work without testing it myself, but, have you tried calling `job:delete-scheduled-job` as the last expression in the Scheduled XQuery?

Comment: I thought of it ... but I instead (for now) opted for the much safer delete it when the next one runs instead of deleting the one I just created. I there are several entry points to the function that runs the query, one of which is this schedule way. But maybe I can think that through \

Comment: Okay, so are you still looking for an answer? or you have managed to resolve this to your satisfaction already?

Comment: I would add that `util:eval-async` has been removed for eXist-db 5, as it was not well supported. I have started implementing EXPath Task for eXist-db, which could be an option for you for asynchronous execution.

Comment: Well @adamretter, I was open for an answer like eval-async() should be used like this or maybe we missed some param that removes jobs from scheduler that are totally done. That would be the real answer and would love to hear it

Comment: Apart from the Scheduler, as far as I know there is not a good asynchronous execution mechanism available over HTTP in eXist-db at present.

Comment: That is great information @adamretter, thank you. We will put this into a function module for us ... we basically call a query now that schedules itself ... essentially calls itself with an additional parameter that it is scheduled which (if scheduled is true) it triggers the actual task instead of scheduling it. Funky but fun. Works like a charm so far